# Is it possible to build generic forms in Java

Tags: java, forms, performance, generics

Is it possible to build generic forms in Java for inserting different types of data on different number of fields for each domain class? And if possible, would the app run faster than creating separate form for each domain class? 
Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about just making generic classes? Because that is possible in Java

Comment: I`m not sure, but what I need is to create one JFrame and then dynamically change or hide fields when its needed by domain class.

Comment: Oh I think I know what you're talking about. You might be able to do it using instanceof to check what type of object it its then build your jFrame accordingly but there may be a better way I just dont know about.

Comment: Faster?  Maybe, maybe not.  But it is guaranteed to be ugly and barely unusable.  It's not enough for a user interface to be functionally correct—it needs to organized in a *readable* manner.  Showing a bunch of fields, row by row, as a contiguous wall of text, is pretty much the opposite of usability.  Create your user interfaces manually, one by one, with readable layouts in mind.  (There are many books and web pages dedicated to good user interface design.)  Your software will be much better.

Comment: I think it doesnt have to be ugly if it create it though the code, especially if you take time and keep in mind to manage distances for different screen sizes. All I want is not to waste time for creating ui every time I am developing an app, and then not getting paid for

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it is possible.
However, this is a design decision that needs to be considered carefully and you need to take into account many factors when deciding whether you want to build the forms dynamically or manually.

**How many forms do you need to create, and will the number of forms needed, increase later?**
If this is true, then you might consider developing a DSL (Domain Specific Language) what would allow you to easily design a form, and have a class that knows how to read the DSL and create the form accordingly.

**If the number of forms is limited** and you only need to create them once (no forms will be added later), then you might consider developing them manually (if it's faster than writing code that would dynamically create them, of course writing code that will create forms dynamically based on some parameters would require more thought).

I'll provide you with a very simple example of what I mean above. Here's an example of a method I've developed to dynamically create a calendar based on the year and month you select and display buttons which can be clicked and let you select a `checkbox` which specifies whether the day you have selected is a "Paid" leave or not. **Note**: this is only the method that constructs the calendar, not the whole form which has other functionalities. But this part is constructed dynamically, so I'm enclosing only this.

```
private void constructCalendar()
{
    int index = 1;
    int day = 1;
    int columns = ((GridLayout) daysPanel.getLayout()).getColumns();
    int rows = ((GridLayout) daysPanel.getLayout()).getRows();
    int selectedYear = Integer.parseInt(year.getValue().toString());
    int month = monthsList.getSelectedIndex();
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(selectedYear, month, 1);

    String[] days = select.getWeekDays();

    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        JLabel lab = new JLabel(days[i - 1]);
        lab.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lab.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
        lab.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 14));
        if (i == 6 || i == 7)
        {
            lab.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
        daysPanel.add(lab);
    }
    for (int i = columns; i >= 2; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= rows; j++)
        {
            if (index >= (gc.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 5) % 7 + 1 && day <= gc.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
            {
                daysPanel.add(new LeaveItem("" + day, "Paid", addList, removeList, year.getValue().toString(), "" + (month + 1), leaveDays));
                day++;
            } else
            {
                daysPanel.add(new JLabel());
            }
            index++;
        }
    }

}
```

In each box (representing a day) it adds a `LeaveItem`. And here's the code for the `LeaveItem` class.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;


public class LeaveItem extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{

    private JToggleButton button;
    private JCheckBox isPaid;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> addList;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> removeList;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> leaveDays;
    private String year;
    private String month;
    private boolean insertIntoAddList = true;
    private String key = "";

    public LeaveItem(String buttonText, String checkBoxText, HashMap<String, Integer> addList, HashMap<String, Integer> removeList,
            String year, String month, HashMap<String, Integer> leaveDays)
    {
        this.addList = addList;
        this.removeList = removeList;
        this.leaveDays = leaveDays;
        this.year = year;
        this.month = (month.length() == 1 ? "0" : "") + month;
        button = new JToggleButton(buttonText);
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(year), Integer.parseInt(month) - 1, Integer.parseInt(buttonText));
        if (gc.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == GregorianCalendar.SUNDAY
                || gc.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == GregorianCalendar.SATURDAY)
        {
            Font currentFont = button.getFont();
            button.setFont(new Font(currentFont.getName(), Font.BOLD, currentFont.getSize()));
            button.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
        button.setBackground(Color.white);
        isPaid = new JCheckBox(checkBoxText);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        isPaid.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 200));
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        isPaid.setSelected(true);
        isPaid.addActionListener(this);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        this.setVisible(true);
        key = this.year + "-" + this.month + "-" + ((button.getText().length() == 1 ? "0" : "") + button.getText());
        Integer tempLeaveDay = this.leaveDays.get(key);
        if (tempLeaveDay != null)
        {
            isPaid.setSelected(tempLeaveDay == 1 ? true : false);
            insertIntoAddList = false;
            button.doClick();
            insertIntoAddList = true;
        } else if (this.addList.containsKey(key))
        {
            isPaid.setSelected(this.addList.get(key) == 1 ? true : false);
            button.doClick();
        }
    }

    public JToggleButton getButton()
    {
        return this.button;
    }

    public JCheckBox getCheckBox()
    {
        return this.isPaid;
    }

    public boolean isPaid()
    {
        return this.isPaid.isSelected();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JToggleButton)
        {
            if (button.isSelected())
            {
                this.add(isPaid, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                removeList.remove(key);
                if (insertIntoAddList)
                {
                    addList.put(key, isPaid.isSelected() ? 1 : 0);
                }
            } else
            {
                this.remove(isPaid);
                addList.remove(key);
                removeList.put(key, isPaid.isSelected() ? 1 : 0);
            }
        } else if (source instanceof JCheckBox)
        {
            //if (addList.containsKey(key))
            {
                addList.put(key, isPaid.isSelected() ? 1 : 0);
            }
        }
        this.validate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen what you`ve been doing there, pretty elegant solution for your needs. What I would use dynamic form creation for is to connect an app to a database, create domain classes and then call form factory to build forms for me cause lets face it it takes most of the time..